# I can move elements within the std::list without invalidating iterators nor references, but how?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stdlist

From [cppreference article on `std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

> Addition, removal and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted.

And indeed, this is the case while sorting elements. From [cppreference article on `std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort):

> This function also differs from `std::sort` in that it does not require the element type of the list to be swappable, preserves the values of all iterators, and performs a stable sort.

But how may I arbitrarily swap the positions of two elements while preserving the values of all iterators?

For example, assume I have a list:

```
std::list<int> l({1, 2, 3, 4});
auto it = l.begin(), jt = ++l.begin();
```

Now `it` points to `1` and `jt` points to `2`. Can I reorder this list so that `2` comes before `1`, but `it` still points to `1`?

I can do:

```
std::swap(*it, *jt);
```

But then, while `2` will come before `1`, I will not preserve the values of iterators, since clearly `it` will point to `2`.

Given the aforementend citation from cppreference, I suppose it should be possible to achieve what I want to achieve; but how?

Edit: To make things clear: One more example:

```
std::list<int> l({2, 1, 3, 4, 5});
auto it = l.begin(), jt = ++l.begin();
```

Now `it` points to `2` and `jt` points to `1`.

`std::list::sort` has the semantics I'm looking for:

```
l.sort();
```

Now the list's ordering is: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, however `it` is still pointing at `2` and `jt` is still pointing at `1`.

On the other hand, `std::swap(it, jt)` nor `std::swap(*it, *jt)` does not have the semantics I want. Calling any of them will make `it` point to `1` and `jt` point to `2`. ([ideone proof](https://ideone.com/GRcEo3))

Comment: It's a doubly linked list.  When moving an element you only have to adjust the pointers to and from the neighbouring elements.

Comment: The elements in doubly linked lists are not 'moved' when swapped. Their pointers to the next and previous elements change instead

Comment: @HenriMenke Trivial if I'd implement a doubly linked list myself; but how to do this with `std::list`?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia article of "double linked list", you will understand how it works and you will find yourself how to do it.

Comment: [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)

Comment: `std::list` **IS** a doubly linked list...

Comment: @Fureeish While `std::list` is very clearly a doubly linked list, I think it is reasonable that I try to stick to the official interface and not try to mess with its implementation, given that it is a standard library facility.

Comment: @Oliv, see above.

Comment: @gaazkam Actualy you cannot do what you want as efficiently as `sort` because I don't know why in C++17 they do not have offered us the possibility to extract list nodes...

Comment: @JesperJuhl , however, unlike vectors, std::list allows me to do what I'm asking for in this question. Also we can remove elements from the middle of a std::list in a constant time, while vector confines us to linear time. Is `std::vector`'s linear time actually better than `std::list`'s constant time?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yup. Or as I like to say: No matter what the question is, a linked list is the wrong answer

Comment: @Nemo Then my honest question is, could you explain me what I'm asking about in my comment to Jesper above?

Comment: @gaazkam: How are you getting a handle to the element you are removing? By scanning the list linearly? What is your actual use case? I have honestly seen zero instances in practice when `std::list` was the appropriate data structure.

Comment: @gaazkam The problems with a linked list are: a) to get to the point where you need a change you have to traverse the list (no random access). b) traversing a list means chasing pointers (something a modern CPU really does not like). c) linked list node creation involves heap allocations. I encourage you to benchmark it yourself. Regardless of its theoretical big-O advantage, lists usually end up slower than vector since vector is so much friendlier to the CPU and what it's good at (the prefetcher loves vector). Try it out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But how may I arbitrarily swap the positions of two elements while preserving the values of all iterators?

As suggested by @cpplearner, use [`.splice()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

It can operate on individual elements or ranges. It can also transfer elements across lists.

Here's a simple example demonstrating how to move a single element.

```
std::list<int> list{1,2,3,4,5};

// This element will be moved
auto source = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), 4);

// It will be inserted before this element
auto destination = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), 2);

list.splice(destination, list, source);
// ^                      ^
// |                      `- A list to move from
// `- A list to move to   

// Prints `1 4 2 3 5`.
for (int it : list) std::cout << it << ' ';
```

Comment: Thank you. I must say I was, at first, perplexed by [what cppreference has to say about splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice): "Transfers elements from one list to **another**". My first impression was that therefore, it would prob be some kind of UB to use splice to move elements within the same list. However, it is worth noting that on complexity analysis cppreference explicitely mentions the possibility that splice may be used on one list, not two lists, and it seems to be working in practice ([ideone swap example](https://ideone.com/i5Lkx9))

Answer (score -1):

You're swapping values.  Not iterator values.  So the iterators stay the same, while the values they point to change (are swapped).

Think about iterators like pointers, at least in this respect.

So what you would do to swap the iterators and the values is just that:

```
std::swap(*it, *jt);
std::swap(it, jt);
```

Comment: OP is asking how to do it with `std::list`, not why it's possible.

Comment: I see.  I'll change my answer.

Comment: "So what you would do to swap the iterators and the values is just that: std::swap(*it, *jt); std::swap(it, jt);" Tested. Not working. https://ideone.com/bpyMs2

Comment: He wants the order of the element to be changed. That will not do it.

Comment: Please see my edited question, perhaps this time I managed to be more clear.

Comment: `int main()
{
    list<int> l{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto jt = l.begin(),
         it = jt++;
    swap(*it, *jt);
    swap(it, jt);
    for (auto v : l)
    {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
`
Output :: 2 1 3 4

Comment: @SidS OP wants to leverage special properties of linked lists to reorder elements by adjusting internal pointers, not by swapping contents.